# Fortran "archaic" type-specific mathematical functions

Tags: fortran

I am working on a project that was started a couple of years ago. Recently there is a new member in the group who suggests replacing all the archaic type-specific forms of mathematical functions with the generic ones. For example, it is suggested that both `cdexp(c)` and `dexp(d)` be replaced by `exp(c)` and `exp(d)`. However another member that has been on the project for years is reluctant to do so because he thinks that `dexp(d)` double checks the type of `d` and make sure that we don't accidentally passes a complex parameter as real and make a bug like in the following code snippet:

```
program main
  real*8     ::  a = 3.d0
  real*8     ::  b = 2.d0
  complex*16 ::  c = (7.d0, 8.d0)
  a = b + exp(c)
  write(6,*) a                                                                                                                                                                                               
end program main
```

vs.

```
program main
  real*8     ::  a = 3.d0
  real*8     ::  b = 2.d0
  complex*16 ::  c = (7.d0, 8.d0)
  a = b + dexp(c)
  write(6,*) a                                                                                                                                                                                                
end program main
```

The first one will give unexpected result while the second one gives error at compile time, assuming that we expect `c` to be real but may have carelessly passed something complex into it. What is shown above is a minimal example so everyone can see `c` is complex at first sight. The real case is much more complex than this.

My question is, does this claim justify the use of the archaic type-specific mathematical Fortran functions, or should we really listen to the suggestion and replace the type-specific functions with the more general ones?

Any help will be appreciated.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047922/dexp-or-exp-for-exponential-function-in-fortran) before I post. The answer there simply says the archaic ones are archaic and the general one can handle the parameter type automatically. It is not mentioned at all, that the archaic form is useful for **double checking the type** and allows for some bugs to be discovered at **compile time**. I think the concerns in this question is clearly different from that one.

Comment: I have checked the answer in the possible duplicate **before** I posted this. The answer there is not really helpful, I must say.

Comment: If the link does not answer your question, please modify it so that it stresses the point not discussed there so that we don't have to repeat. **Always** reference a relevant question, if you read it, to prevent this. Explain why it is not helpful.

Comment: **Not sure what's the issue, but this is in response to a comment which now seems to be deleted. I have kept this comment since it provides some more information about the question.** Sorry but I don't find it straightforward.I think it does provide a level of type-safety(point it out if I am wrong), but I don't know whether it is enough to justify the use of archaic functions, or we should stop using the archaic functions because they are archaic. Can you elaborate it or provide me a link to find relevant information? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for explaining and reopening the question. That's fair enough.

Comment: @VladimirF Indeed you are correct, I have removed the comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @kvantour It was a valid point, no need to delete. Actually, I am now investigating it in more detail.

Comment: a good question here are these things flagged as obsolescent by the current standard? If so that gives you ammunition to argue against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the old form is useful. The error checking is dubious. You can check against implicit conversions from double to real using compiler options.

Using the old form will harm the genericity of the code. You cannot then simply recompile your code with a different set of kind parameters. Although, when you use the non-standard `real*4` and `real*8` you can't easily change the kinds either. This is a major reason for me, I routinely change between single and double precision just by recompiling with a different kind constant.

For example, with your first code, you get a warning:

```
> gfortran -Wall dexp.f90 
dexp.f90:5.6:

  a = b + exp(c)
      1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from COMPLEX(8) to REAL(8) at (1)
```

To catch a single precision variable used instead of a double, you have to enable `Wconversion-extra`:

```
> gfortran -Wconversion-extra dexp.f90 
dexp.f90:5.7:

  a =  exp(c)
       1
Warning: Conversion from REAL(4) to REAL(8) at (1)
```

Some compilers will not be able to catch this (Intel?) and your colleague might have some point, but I don't believe it overcomes the ugliness of `dexp()` and similar.

Comment: I have check with intel and solarisstudio. Both compilers cannot give warnings for implicit conversions.

Comment: related https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/269439